# See the marker on the map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Create model for my marker:

```
public class FirebaseMarker {

public String dob;
public String dod;
public String name;
public double latitude;
public double longitude;

public FirebaseMarker() {
}

public FirebaseMarker(String name, double latitude, double longitude, String dob, String dod) {
    this.name = name;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.dob = dob;
    this.dod = dod;
}
```

Also create getters and setters for all this parametrs, after this i created class MapActivity(this activity i open when press on item in my recyclerView)

```
  public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
DatabaseReference mProfileRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Profile");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    createMapView();

    FirebaseMarker marker = new FirebaseMarker("Lincoln", -34.506081, 150.88104, "24/12/1940", "02/07/2016");
    FirebaseMarker marker2 = new FirebaseMarker("Lincoln", -35.506081, 140.88104, "24/12/1940", "02/07/2016");
    mProfileRef.push().setValue(marker);
    mProfileRef.push().setValue(marker2);
}

private void createMapView() {
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    LatLng wollongong = new LatLng(-34.404336, 150.881632);
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(wollongong, 18));
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    addMarkersToMap(googleMap);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    if (mChildEventListener != null)
        mProfileRef.removeEventListener(mChildEventListener);
    super.onStop();
}

private void addMarkersToMap(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mChildEventListener = mProfileRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            FirebaseMarker marker = dataSnapshot.getValue(FirebaseMarker.class);
            double latitude = marker.getLatitude();
            double longitude = marker.getLongitude();
            String name = marker.getName();
            LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(name));
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

But when i open the activity i see just a map, how i can see the **marker**?

Answer (score 0):

You Define Variable

```
GoogleMap googleMap;
```

and in

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
```

they are the same
so what about try to rename it

so

```
GoogleMap MgoogleMap;
```

and edit **onMapReady**

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
 MgoogleMap =googleMap
    addMarkersToMap(MgoogleMap );

}
```

Comment: same situation( i didn t see the marker. Mb i need to use seOnMarkerClickListener?